# using variable name to dynamically grab data

Tags: php, content-management-system, block, mybb

This is probably a fairly unique situation, however I am writing some custom code for myBB. It is essentially a small CMS whereby part of it allows users to define blocks and block areas and fill those block areas with code.

The way I want this to function is that the user creates a block area and then defines its position inside a template. As the user can define any block name they want and place them in any area they want, I am having trouble getting my head around just how to handle this in code.

My thoughts were that I could have the user define a variable in their template named block_blockarea_name, I could then grab that the variable and then parse the name of the variable remove "block_" then use the rest of the name to check for any block that is assigned to that area name. I am trying to do this on a custom page rather than through a plugin itself.

The only other option i have is to have a marker like  and use a find and replace on that.

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas or suggestions on a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to include a template in a custom PHP page on MyBB? I always use this to output things like the header, maybe yours would work in the same way:

```
<?php
output_page("{$header}");
?>
```